# Fill DIV with image when a LI tag is clicked (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Forgive me as this is probably an easy question for your jQuery guys out there, but I have the following:

1. Unordered list with images as list items
2. Empty div box with dotted border to show that it's empty

I want the user to be able to click on a list item and have the empty div fill with it's image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
$('ul li:has(img)').click(function() {
    $('#divBox').append($('img', this).clone()); 
});
```

**EDIT**: Fixed first version.

Or, alternatively,

```
$('ul li:has(img)').click(function() {
    $('#divBox #imageElem').attr('src', $('img', this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Very impressive and great solution, but how to keep the image in the list? And also SET the image in the DIV and not append it. If I use your solution it keeps adding the images to the div while removing them from the unordered list.

Comment: I tried and I can't get the alternative to work quite yet (I even changed your "atr" to "attr") I'm confident it's my stupid error and not your code...

Comment: You need to change the selector (`'#divBox #imageElem'`) to match your HTML.

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w, try `$('#divBox').append($('<img />').attr('src', $('img', this).attr('src')));`

Posting as a comment rather than an answer because I think this is what @SLaks meant (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Er. Yeah. It just seemed there was a mystery `#imageElem` that was never specified before heh.